# Открытие файла

Tags: android, java

Как в Android открыть файл (например, изображение) средствами системы. То есть чтобы файл открылся в приложении, которое предусмотрена для этого типа.

**Обновлено.**

Для того, чтобы система могла понять, какими приложениями она может открыть файл, надо явно указать mime-type. В библиотеке есть специальный класс для работы с mime-types: `android.webkit.MimeTypeMap`.

Для того чтобы получить mime-type мы сначала узнаем расширение файла.

```
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
String mType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
```

Но такой код работать не будет, т.к.

- Метод `getFileExtensionFromUrl` возвращает расширение верно, только если имя файла содержит только латинские символы (без пробелов, без кириллицы, и т.д.).
- Метод `getMimeTypeFromExtension` работает верно, только если расширение в нижним регистре (так что добавляем `toLowerCase`).

Далее. Если настроить intent так

```
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file)); 
intent.setType(mType);
```

то будет установлен только `type`, а `data` будет равна `null`. Если строчки поменять местами, то, наоборот, `type == null`. Т.е. либо одно, либо другое. Заработало всё только так:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mType);
```

(тестировал на девайсе от "Моторола")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Открыть файл весьма просто:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/file.xls"));
startActivity(intent);
```

В Uri.parse передаётся абсолютный путь к нужному файлу. Вместо Uri.parse можно указать готовый Uri, если он у вас есть в приложении.

Если указанный файл может открыть только одно приложение, файл будет открыт сразу, если несколько - будет показан диалог выбора нужного приложения. Если же такой тип файла ни одно приложение в системе открыть не может, будет показано стандартное системное сообщение об этом.

Comment: @Dr Zoidberg, У меня почему-то без явного указания `mime-type` не заработало.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить определенный intent-filter в манифест, но приложение должно быть готово ловить этот фильтр. Фильтр может быть своим собственным.
Вот дока - [тыц](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) 
И пример из нее:

```
<intent-filter . . . >
<data android:mimeType="video/mpeg" android:scheme="http" . . . /> 
<data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg" android:scheme="http" . . . />
. . .
</intent-filter>
```

Полезно будет ознакомиться с примером:
[тыц](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#npex)

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: ) вопрос: как в адроиде.... ?
)) ответ: http://developer.android.com/

Comment: Автор спрашивал как из своего приложения открыть какой-либо файл в ассоциированном с этим типом файлов приложении. А вы ему рассказываете как ассоциировать свое приложение с определенным типом файлов.

Comment: Вопросы нужно задавать поточнее, имхо. Телепатией не владею. Вторая часть вопроса автора сбила с толку, она лишняя в таком случае.